# How to copy a dataframe to the clipboard such that when pasted, the ouptut is the same as when copying manually from the console of RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, clipboard

I want to copy a dataframe to the clipboard so as to paste it in an email.

I tried `clipr::write_clip` and `write.table` but none of those solutions renders a well-formatted output (the names of the columns are shifted)

When I copy from the console of RStudio, it works though.

```r
df <-  data.frame(Column1 = c(0.2222, 0.1), Column2 = c("Valeur3", "Valeur4"))
print(df)

  Column1 Column2
1  0.2222 Valeur3
2  0.1000 Valeur4
```

Comment: Have you tried monospaced fonts?

Comment: How the email displays on their end is hard to control. Perhaps you could try a tab-separated format via `write_tsv`.

Comment: @asd-tm Why do you mean? I let the default font

Comment: @FloydEverest I tried `readr::write_tsv(df, "clipboard")` but nothing was copied to the clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you are using default fonts in your email client.
Most of such fonts are proportional.

See the screenshot of your sample pasted into text processor with default (proportional) font:

[image]

For code, scripts and alike text it is necessary to use so called monospace fonts that have save width of symbols. Such fonts are used by stackowerflow when text is formatted as code:

```
  Column1 Column2
1  0.2222 Valeur3
2  0.1000 Valeur4
```

Proportional fonts are used by Stackowerflow for plain text:

Column1 Column2

1  0.2222 Valeur3

2  0.1000 Valeur4

See here the screenshot from the same text processor with monospace font set:

[image]

It is exactly the same clipboard content pasted into the same window. The text copied from RStudio console is plain text and so when pasted the text processor sets the last or default one that is commonly proportional (the letters have different widths depending upon optical density of symbols). You can select a font of your choice. See the list for instance at [Wikipedia](https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.489a60e1-66044a70-cfb94ef2-74722d776562/https/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces)

Comment: But how to select the font with code in R?

Comment: @Julien You do not need to select a font in R. You copy plain text from RStudio (the copied text fragment does not have font set). And then paste it into the window of another program that allows usage of various fonts usage (supports ritch text formatting) and set a monospace font there as I have shown

Comment: @Julien Anyway you can set font in your RStudio settings:  Tools -> Global options and in window Options set Appearance -> Editor font (in my instance Lucida Console is set)